# how to access all documents from all subcollections having same collection Id

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection named " categories " and in that I have 5 documents and every document is having a Collection named "Images" , and the Collection("Images") which is in all the five documents have a field named "artist_name" !

I want to access all the documents from every collection having id "Images" with same artist_name [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vb9aM.png)
[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzMx6.png)

Comment: To understand it better, you need to query all `images` sub-collections, to get the documents where the `artist_name` field holds a particular name, right?

Comment: all those 6 documents are having a collection with same Id "Images" , I want to access the documents from all those 6 **collections having same artist name , lets say artist name == "grajoy" , I want to fetch every document which is having this name ,

Comment: its possible buy querying it 6 times for all those 6 different documents and then merging the list by .addAll() method . but there must be a way to do it in one query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for, is called a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). So to get all documents from all sub-collection where `artist name == "grajoy"`, you should use the following query:

```
val db = Firebase.firestore
val queryByArtistName = db.collectionGroup("images").whereEuqlTo("artist_name", "grajoy")
```

Be aware that the collection is called `images`, and not `Images` (capital I), as I saw in the screenshot.

Comment: ohh it worked ! thank you soo much .. you saved my day . I subscribed your YouTube .. just wanted to explore Firebase ..its too awesome